# Splitting a list by first character of each element

Tags: python, list, group-by, split, python-2.7

I have a Python list `mylist` whose elements are a sublist containing a string of a letter and number. I was wondering how I could split `mylist` by the character at the start of the string without using code with individual statements/cases for each character.
Say I want to split mylist into lists `a, b, c`:

```
mylist = [['a1'],['a2'],['c1'],['b1']]
a = [['a1'],['a2']]
b = [['b1']]
c = [['c1']]
```

It is important that I keep them as a list-of-lists (even though it's only a single element in each sublist).

Comment: It's better to store your result in a dict, keyed on first letter (per Óscar López's answer), rather than individual hardcoded variable names `a, b, c...`; it's better to disregard that requirement.

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
import itertools as it

mylist  = [['a1'],['a2'],['c1'],['b1']]
keyfunc = lambda x: x[0][0]

mylist = sorted(mylist, key=keyfunc)
a, b, c = [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(mylist, keyfunc)]
```

The line where `sorted()` is used is necessary only if the elements in `mylist` are not already sorted by the character at the start of the string.

**EDIT :**

As pointed out in the comments, a more general solution (one that does not restrict the number of variables to just three) would be using dictionary comprehensions (available in Python 2.7+) like this:

```
result_dict = {k: list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(mylist, keyfunc)}
```

Now the answer is keyed in the dictionary by the first character:

```
result_dict['a']
> [['a1'],['a2']]

result_dict['b']
> [['b1']]

result_dict['c']
> [['c1']]
```

Comment: Nice solution, but maybe it should be made clear that the code would crash if there was a 'd1' in the list. That said it would be nicer to replace last row with `result_dict  = {k: list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(mylist, keyfunc)}` which then will have the letters as keys and the lists as items...

Comment: Neat. No need to write `mylist = sorted(mylist, ...)`, just do `mylist.sort(...)` in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary could work too

```
mylist = [['a1'],['a2'],['c1'],['b1']]

from collections import defaultdict

dicto = defaultdict(list)

for ele in mylist:
    dicto[ele[0][0]].append(ele)
```

Result:

```
>>> dicto
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [['a1'], ['a2']], 'c': [['c1']], 'b': [['b1']]})
```

It does not give the exact result you were asking for; however, it is quite easy to access a list of lists associated with each letter

```
>>> dicto['a']
[['a1'], ['a2']]
```

Comment: I +1 this one because it works with any number of starting characters, so you aren't limited to `a`, `b`, `c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get these sublists by using a simple function:

```
def get_items(mylist, letter):
  return [item for item in mylist if item[0][0] == letter]
```

The expression `item[0][0]` simply means to get the first letter of the first element of the current item. You can then call the function for each letter:

```
a = get_items(mylist, 'a')
b = get_items(mylist, 'b')
c = get_items(mylist, 'c')
```